# calculate instead of adding number in javascript

Tags: javascript

in this var: `var previousmenu = $("#ipadmenu section.current").data('order') + 1;`, this expression `$("#ipadmenu section.current").data('order')` equals 0.

Unfortunately the result of this is 01 and not 1. Why is this?

This for example seems to work:
`var previousmenu = $("#ipadmenu section.current").data('order') - 1;` and gives me -1.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` serves two purposes.  It adds in the case of numbers and concatenates in the case of strings.  You can fix this by casting the string as a number with this:

```
var previousmenu = Number($("#ipadmenu section.current").data('order')) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If one the variables you are 'adding' is a string, javascript decides that what you really wanted to do was concatenate the string and the number together (hence "0" + 1 = "01");

What you need to do is something like..

```
var order = parseInt($("#ipadmenu section.current").data('order'), 10);
order = order + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a string, not an integer, thus doing string concatenation... aaand welcome to the whacky world of JavaScript, because you guessed it, "0" - 1 will return a number.

In any case, use `parseInt(...)` or `+ $("blah").data('order') + 1` and you'll be happier, if not confused.